# Остановка предыдущей корутины перед запуском следующей

Tags: c#, unity3d, coroutine

У меня есть три корутины. Я хотел бы сделать так, что бы после выполнения определенного условия, корутина прекращала свою работу и запускала следующую.

```
    IEnumerator pos1(GameObject par1, GameObject par2, GameObject par3)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RectTransform rect123 = par1.GetComponent<RectTransform>();            

            if (rect123.rotation.eulerAngles.y <= 90 )
            {
                rect123.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
            }
            else 
            {
                par1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = cards[1];
                if (rect123.rotation.eulerAngles.y < 180)
                {
                    rect123.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine(pos2(par2, par3));
                    StopCoroutine("pos1");
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator pos2(GameObject par, GameObject par2)
    {
        while (true)
        {
           RectTransform rect223 = par.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

           if (rect223.rotation.eulerAngles.y <= 90 && rect223.anchoredPosition.y <= -116.2f)
            {
                rect223.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
            }

            else
            {
                par.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = cards[1];
                if (rect223.rotation.eulerAngles.y <= 180)
                {
                    rect223.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
                }
                else
                {
                    StartCoroutine(pos3(par2));

                    StopCoroutine("pos2");
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

        }

    }

    IEnumerator pos3(GameObject par)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            RectTransform rect333= par.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

            if (rect333.rotation.eulerAngles.y <= 90)
            {
                rect333.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                par.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = cards[1];
                if (rect333.rotation.eulerAngles.y <= 180)
                {
                    rect333.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 2, 0));
                }
                else
                {
                    StopCoroutine("pos3");
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
        }
    }
```

В итоге получилось что первая корутина запускает безудержно вторую, а та, в свою очередь третью. Почему метод StopCoroutine("pos1"); не работает? и как можно реализовать то, что я задумал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать вот так:

```
IEnumerator F123 () {
    yield return StartCoroutine (F1 ());
    yield return StartCoroutine (F2 ());
    yield return StartCoroutine (F3 ());
}
```

Корутины выполнятся одна за другой.

Предполагается, что проверка условий находится в корутинах F1, F2 и F3:

```
IEnumerator F1 () {
    while (CheckCondition ()) {
        DoSomething ();
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для выборочной остановки корутин можно использовать следующий метод:
при старте корутины присваиваете переменной `Coroutine` возвращаемое значение метода `StartCoroutine`

```
private Coroutine runCoroutine;

//место, где запускается корутина Pos1
private void OnCoroutine()
{
  //Проверяем, есть ли запущенная корутина
  if (runCoroutine != null)
    StopCoroutine(runCoroutine);
  //Запускаем корутину, не забываем про присваивание
  runCoroutine = StartCoroutine(Pos1());
}

//место, где останавливаем конкретно корутину Pos1
private OnStopPos1()
{
  if (runCoroutine != null)
    StopCoroutine(runCoroutine);
}
```